# Using NgMask in a AngularGrid table dynamically

Tags: angularjs, masking, angular-grid

I'd like to use `NgMask` in an `angularGrid` table to edit fields, but I don't know how.
The information from table cames from PHP and fields change depending on the search.
How could I implement it?
Link to NgMask: http://candreoliveira.github.io/bower_components/angular-mask/examples/index.html#/

The angularGrid code with a example:

```
var module = angular.module("example", ["angularGrid"]);
module.controller("exampleCtrl", function($scope, $timeout) {

var columnDefs = [
    {displayName: "Default String", field: "defaultString", width: 150,     editable: true, volatile: true, cellRenderer: cellRenderer, newValueHandler:     numberNewValueHandler},
    {displayName: "Upper Case Only", field: "upperCaseOnly", width: 150, volatile: true, editable: true, cellRenderer: cellRenderer, newValueHandler: numberNewValueHandler},
    {displayName: "Number", field: 'number', width: 150, volatile: true, editable: true, cellRenderer: cellRenderer, newValueHandler: numberNewValueHandler},
    {displayName: "Custom With Angular", field: "setAngular", width: 175, editable: true, volatile: true, cellRenderer: cellRenderer, newValueHandler: numberNewValueHandler},
    {displayName: "Custom No Angular", field: "setNoAngular", width: 175, cellRenderer: cellRendererLink, cellTemplate: '<a href="#">{{row.entity[col.field]}}</a>'
```

}];

```
var data = [
    {ID:111, defaultString: 'APPLE', upperCaseOnly: 'APPLE', number: 11, setAngular: 'AAA', setNoAngular: 'AAA'},
    {ID:222, defaultString: 'ORANGE', upperCaseOnly: 'ORANGE', number: 22, setAngular: 'BBB', setNoAngular: 'BBB'},
    {ID:333, defaultString: 'BANANA', upperCaseOnly: 'BANANA', number: 33, setAngular: 'CCC', setNoAngular: 'CCC'},
    {ID:444, defaultString: 'PEAR', upperCaseOnly: 'PEAR', number: 44, setAngular: 'DDD', setNoAngular: 'DDD'}
];

$scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: data,
    enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
    enableSorting: true,
    enableFilter: true,
};

});
```

I dont want to use `ui-grid` or something, just `angularGrid` and some mask.

Comment: To what property do you like to apply the mask?

Comment: To validate the edited value. There are a lot of differents fields: plate, cnpj, dates, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could dynamically create the `columnsDef` and specify in the `editableCellTemplate` your required mask.

The code works like this:

1. Get the data from server
2. Create fields from data keys
3. Extend the keys with the `mappingObj`.
4. Set `mappedData` to the scope, so `ngGrid` updates.

You could probably also add a validation property to your data and use this to create the column definition.

The uppercase mask is not working properly. I don't know what's wrong. If you enter some uppercase chars and then quickly a lowercase char it will be possible to enter.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/QCSJV4kEyVHpuObEgSrb?p=preview).

```js
// main.js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid', 'ngMask']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    /*$scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50, personalId: '123-234-445'},
                     {name: "Tiancum", age: 43, personalId: '223-234-445'},
                     {name: "Jacob", age: 27,personalId: '323-234-445'},
                     {name: "Nephi", age: 29, personalId: '423-234-445'},
                     {name: "Enos", age: 34, personalId: '523-234-445'}];
    */
    $scope.myData = [];
    $scope.colDef = [];
    /*
    var columnDef = [{ field: 'name', displayName: 'First Name', width: 90 },
                     { field: 'age', width:50, cellClass: 'ageCell', headerClass: 'ageHeader', 
                       editableCellTemplate: '<input type="number" ng-class="\'colt\' + col.index" ng-input="COL_FIELD" ng-model="COL_FIELD" />' },
                       { field: 'personalId', displayName: 'ID', width: 150, editableCellTemplate: '<input ng-model="COL_FIELD" ng-input="COL_FIELD" mask="255-255-255"/>'}];
      
    */        
    $http.jsonp('http://www.mocky.io/v2/559304993c82b23c10eea6a6?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').then(function(response){
      //'http://www.mocky.io/v2/5592fc513c82b22510eea699?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').then(function (response){      
      //$scope.colDef=response.data;//["ColumnName":data.something]    
      var data = response.data,
          keys = [],
          curKeys = '',
          mappedData,
          mappingObject = {
            /*
              name: {
              displayName: 'First Name',
              width: 90
            },*/
            age: {
              width: 50,
              cellClass: 'ageCell',
              headerClass: 'ageHeader',
              editableCellTemplate: '<input type="number" ng-class="\'colt\' + col.index" ng-input="COL_FIELD" ng-model="COL_FIELD" />'
            },
            personalId: {
              displayName: 'ID', 
              width: 150, 
              editableCellTemplate: '<input ng-model="COL_FIELD" ng-input="COL_FIELD" mask="255-255-255"/>'
            },
            upperCaseOnly: {
              displayName: 'uper case only property',
              width: 100,
              editableCellTemplate: '<input ng-model="COL_FIELD" ng-input="COL_FIELD" mask="A" repeat="10" limit="false" restrict="reject"/>'
            }
          };
          
      $scope.myData = data;
      
      data.forEach(function(row, index) {
        curKeys = Object.keys(row);
        console.log(curKeys);
        curKeys.forEach(function(key) {
          if (keys.indexOf(key) == -1)
            keys.push(key);  
        });
      });
      
      mappedData = keys.map(function(key){
        return angular.extend({field: key}, mappingObject[key]);
      });
      console.log(mappedData);
      $scope.colDef = mappedData;
    });
    
    $scope.filter = {filterText:''};
    $scope.gridOptions = {
      data: 'myData',
      enableFiltering: true,
    filterOptions: $scope.filter,
    showFilter: true,
    enableCellEditOnFocus: true, //enables the editor on a single click, if you use enableCellEdit: true you would have to doubleclick
        columnDefs: 'colDef'//columnDef

  };
  
  $scope.showRowCount = function() {
    console.log($scope.gridOptions.ngGrid.filteredRows.length);
  }
});
```

```css
/*style.css*/
.gridStyle {
    border: 1px solid rgb(212,212,212);
    width: 400px; 
    height: 300px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Custom Plunker</title>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/css/ng-grid.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/lib/ng-grid.debug.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/candreoliveira/ngMask/master/dist/ngMask.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <input ng-model="filter.filterText"/>
      <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
        currently visible items: {{gridOptions.ngGrid.filteredRows.length}}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @AWolf. I think you answered my question. Now I have to implement.